# How to show / hide a button on a sheet in libreoffice calc using macros?

Tags: macros, libreoffice-calc

I face a little problem with libreoffice calc v5.1.6.2 as I didn't managed to find how to show / hide a button on a sheet using macros.

I'm talking about buttons directly on the sheet, not the dialog ones (haven't tested on dialogs yet, maybe it will be the same problem...).

So I can enable / disable them by using something like:

```
MyButton.enabled = True (or False)
```

after I populated "MyButton" with the right object, but there is no

```
MyButton.visible = False
```

or

```
MyButton.isVisible = False
```

Despite the fact the "visible" property exists in the editor, right below the "enabled" line in design mode. So how can I acheive that dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XrayTool](http://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html) shows a property with the somewhat unusual name of `EnableVisible`.

```vb
oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
oButton = oSheet.DrawPage.Forms.getByIndex(0).getByName("Push Button 1")
oButton.EnableVisible = False  'Hide the button
```

For this to work, Calc's Design Mode must be off.  If it is on, then all buttons will be shown regardless of their visibility setting.

Note: I could not find this property in the API docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it does not seem to work... I copy-pasted your code and the button stays visible (I'm not in design mode). I can disable it as before, but cannot hide it...

Comment: It worked for me.  Any error messages?  Does the value of `visible` change?  What happens when you manually change `visible` and then switch off Design Mode?  Use an introspection tool such as MRI or XrayTool to verify that the button exists and has the expected name and the `EnableVisible` property.  Also try starting with an empty Calc document and creating a button.  I used "Push Button" in the Form Controls toolbar.

Comment: I can manually switch the button invisible with the designer. For the rest I don't have any error, the button seems to have the "EnableVisible" method (no complain)... I don't know what button I'm using, there is only 1 buton in my toolbar and it is simply called "button"... I will try what you suggested (XrayTool, new empty sheet...) and come back to you.

Comment: Well, after some tests, it indeed works on a fresh new document... Now I have to find out what is wrong with my code! Thanks @Jim K

Comment: Ok got it to work! I was passing the wrong argument in my sub method... Sorry for the inconvenience.